# Printing all elements of a list in vertical format in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to print all elements of a list `A` in vertical format. I present the current and expected output.

```
A=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10],[15,19,21,11,18]]
print(*A)
```

The current output is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10] [15, 19, 21, 11, 18]
```

The expected output is

```
[[1, 
  2, 
  3, 
  4, 
  5, 
  6, 
  7, 
  8, 
  10],
  [15, 
   19, 
   21, 
   11, 
   18]]
```

Comment: `import json; print(json.dumps(a, indent=2))` maybe?

Comment: Why do you expect that output? Have you tried some different code to try to achieve your goal?

Comment: I think they're saying it's the output they wants.  So what code do they write to make that happen.

Comment: Just loop over that with `for` print each element, and separately print the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print` like this:

```
print(
    '[[', '],\n['.join(
        [str(',\n'.join(
            [str(i) for i in j]
        )) for j in A]
    ),
    end=']]',
    sep=''
)
```

Comment: btw it works only when you have `list` of `lists`